# Implement Ethereum Wallet on website

Tags: wallets, light-clients

I want to implement basic ethereum wallet(import wallet, check balance, make transactions, export wallet) for my react SPA.
What would be the best option to use? Do I outsource wallet functionalities to third party apis? if so which one is the most reliable?

Would writing my own wallet be too much hustle or just not worth it?
If there are some other solution please list them too. Would prefer using javascript or python.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look on MetaMask https://metamask.io/

> MetaMask is a bridge that allows you to visit the distributed web of
>   tomorrow in your browser today. It allows you to run Ethereum dApps
>   right in your browser without running a full Ethereum node.
>
> MetaMask includes a secure identity vault, providing a user interface
>   to manage your identities on different sites and sign blockchain
>   transactions.

Another option is to include your React SAP into a Parity client. Take a look on a tutorial here https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Tutorial-Part-I